# handling spikes in ARIMA model residual components

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to predict sales values using time series approach. Below graph is the sales for a store over a period of 942 days (sales will be 0 when the store is closed and are not plotted in first 2 graphs for sake for clarity in graph):

[image: Complete time series]

Stacking yearly sales give us a graph like below:

[image: Sales per year stacked over each other]

It looked like it may be worth investing in time series, so I tried drawing the acf and pacf graphs which are shown below:

[image: ACF plot]

[image: PACF]

The strong auto correlation in the curve suggest the presence of time series. So I applied, `auto.arima()` function from `r` to just look at how it performs (`salesModel <- auto.arima(saleDataSeries)`). Below is the residuals plot from arima. I tested the prediction on Kaggle Leaderboard and the approach did not perform that well(competition is over now).

[image: Residual]

Model Parameters:

```
Series: saleDataSeries 
ARIMA(5,1,4)                    

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      ar3      ar4      ar5      ma1     ma2     ma3
      -0.0885  -0.1938  -0.5965  -0.3084  -0.3058  -0.8985  0.0040  0.7063
s.e.   0.1036   0.0634   0.0451   0.0329   0.0690   0.1202  0.0704  0.0909
          ma4
      -0.6996
s.e.   0.0296

sigma^2 estimated as 4621003:  log likelihood=-8555.57
AIC=17115.2   AICc=17115.43   BIC=17163.67
```

Currently I am also looking at multiple seasonality using `tbats`, but I believe that there can be certain modifications that can be made to simple ARIMA model as the ACF/PACF graph still have some spikes in the residual component. I am unsure why this is happening and any insights would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

ARIMA modelling (by itself) is of little use with your kind of data . See my response to [Time series analysis to quantify trend when seasonal amplitude is decreasing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186725/time-series-analysis-to-quantify-trend-when-seasonal-amplitude-is-decreasing/186791#186791) as a guide to what can be done. Note that when I answered the post I was unaware that it was an economic series. I specifically disabled the identification of the optimum lead and lag effects around each holiday . I also disabled the identification of particular days in the month and particular weeks in the month that might be of interest. I also disabled long-weekend effects, Monday after a Friday holiday effect, Friday before a Monday Holiday effect, month-end effects etc. as I had no idea that it was economic data. If I had enabled these economically oriented remedies , the results would have been even more amazing. If you wish you can post your data and I will demonstrate that for you.

By the way my "eye" tells me that you have a level shift not a trend but only good exploratory analysis can confirm that.

Comment: The data is publicly available at https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data (one would need to sign up though). The `train.csv` has all the data and I had grouped the data by store and analysing for each store. The data I have posted is for store 6. Let me know if you can't access it.

Comment: Also could you explain, intuitively what assumptions in ARIMA fails one this data?

Comment: Essentially ARIMA is all about memory i.e. leaning on prior values explicitely. In terms of retail daily data one needs to incorporate fixed effects like day-of-the-week , month-of-the-year etc .... Adding level shifts and determinstic trends (like the one you assumed) should be done when needed not by assumption. Combining these effects with ARIMA can often ( read:nearly always) lead to a powerful/efficient model with or without user-specified predictors like weather/price/promotion/#of sales clerks etc. This class of model is called a Transfer Function or a Dynamic Regression.

Comment: LIke all models assumptions regarding stability of coefficients and constancy of error variance along with an error series free of information are important to verify.

Comment: If you wish to form the data as an excel file and email it to me I will be glad to look at it.